# Why might the displayed Accept/Unaccept totals be inconsistent with the state of the Accepted Answer flag?

Tags: support, reputation, events

I have an [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310737/sending-a-post-query-sent-via-httparty/9312118#9312118) that currently is marked as accepted. However, when you look at my rep totals for that post, you see exactly one `accept` and exactly one `unaccept`.

[image: One Accept and one Unaccept]

It would seem that it is missing one `accept`, as I can't think of any other reason for it to be in this state. What could have caused this inconsistency?

Comment: You're looking at the events that occurred *today*. The original accept was probably some time in the distant past.

Comment: Yep, that's what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9310737/timeline) shows that your answer was first accepted on February 16th, before being unaccepted and reaccepted today. The information you're seeing is correct, and if you browse back to the details for February 16th you should see the initial accept there.

Comment: Thanks! I remember seeing the timeline before, but forgot about it!